# Title: How to render Twitter block in Flutter using flutter_html 4.2.2?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a Flutter app where I'm using the `flutter_html` package version 4.2.2 to render HTML content. I have a custom widget called `_Html` which takes HTML content and renders it using `HtmlWidget`. Here's the code for the `_Html` widget:

```dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cached_network_image/cached_network_image.dart';
import 'package:carousel_slider/carousel_slider.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:html_parser_plus/html_parser_plus.dart' as parserPlus;
import 'package:flutter_screenutil/flutter_screenutil.dart';
import 'package:flutter_widget_from_html/flutter_widget_from_html.dart';
import 'package:html/parser.dart' as parser;
import 'package:html_unescape/html_unescape.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import '../providers/news_provider.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:share/share.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';



import '../widgets/home/show_admob_widget.dart';
import 'fullscreen_image_screen.dart';

class NewsDetailScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final int index;

  const NewsDetailScreen({Key? key, required this.index}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<NewsDetailScreen> createState() => _NewsDetailScreenState();
}

class _NewsDetailScreenState extends State<NewsDetailScreen> {
  final controller = WebViewController()
    ..setJavaScriptMode(JavaScriptMode.unrestricted)
    ..setBackgroundColor(const Color(0x00000000))
    ..setNavigationDelegate(
      NavigationDelegate(
        onProgress: (int progress) {
          // Update loading bar.
        },
        onPageStarted: (String url) {},
        onPageFinished: (String url) {},
        onWebResourceError: (WebResourceError error) {},
        onNavigationRequest: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;
          }
          return NavigationDecision.navigate;
        },
      ),
    )
    ..loadRequest(Uri.parse('https://flutter.dev'));

  List<String> getGalleryItems(Map<String, dynamic> data) {
    if (data.containsKey('galleryItems')) {
      final galleryItems = data['galleryItems'] as List<dynamic>;
      return galleryItems.map((item) => item.toString()).toList();
    }
    return [];
  }

  String removeTwitterBlocks(String htmlContent) {
    final twitterBlockPattern = RegExp(
      r'<blockquote class="twitter-tweet"[^>]*>.*?<\/blockquote>',
      multiLine: true,
      dotAll: true,
    );
    return htmlContent.replaceAll(twitterBlockPattern, '');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final newsProvider = Provider.of<NewsProvider>(context);
    final listItems = newsProvider.allPosts;
    final post = listItems[widget.index];
    final content = post.data['content'];
    final decodedContent = HtmlUnescape().convert(content);
    //final updatedContent = removeTwitterBlocks(decodedContent);
    final paragraphs = extractParagraphs(decodedContent);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        iconTheme: Theme.of(context).iconTheme,
        centerTitle: true,
        title: const Text('News'),
        actions: [
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.share_outlined),
            onPressed: () {
              final title = post.data['title'];
              final guid = post.data['guid'];
              final text = '$title\n\nLees het hele bericht op \n$guid';
              Share.share(text);
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(10)),
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: [
            Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.all(ScreenUtil().setWidth(10)),
              color: Colors.red,
              child: Text(
                post.data['category'],
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                  fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(16),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(10)),
            Text(
              HtmlUnescape().convert('${post.data['title']}'),
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).splashColor,
                fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(18),
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(5)),
            Text(
              '${post.data['author']} - ${formatDate(post.data['date'])}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Theme.of(context).splashColor,
                fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(10)),
            SizedBox(
              height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(200),
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Stack(
                children: [
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: GestureDetector(
                      onTap: () {
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (_) => FullscreenImageScreen(
                              imageUrl: post.data['image'],
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                      child: ClipRRect(
                        borderRadius:
                            BorderRadius.circular(ScreenUtil().setWidth(10)),
                        child: CachedNetworkImage(
                          imageUrl: post.data['image'],
                          fit: BoxFit.cover,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned.fill(
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        gradient: LinearGradient(
                          begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                          end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                          colors: [
                            Colors.transparent,
                            Theme.of(context).focusColor.withOpacity(0.4)
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  if (post.data['imageCaption'] != null)
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: ScreenUtil().setHeight(10),
                      right: ScreenUtil().setWidth(10),
                      child: Container(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: Colors.black54,
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(ScreenUtil().setWidth(4)),
                        ),
                        child: Text(
                          post.data['imageCaption'],
                          maxLines: 2,
                          style: TextStyle(
                            color: Colors.white,
                            fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(12),
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(15)),
            if (paragraphs.isNotEmpty)
              HtmlWidget(
                paragraphs[0],
                customStylesBuilder: (e) {
                  switch (e.localName) {
                    case 'em':
                      return {'color': '#f00'};
                  }

                  return null;
                },
                customWidgetBuilder: (e) {
                  if (e.localName == 'blockquote') {
                    switch (e.attributes['class']) {
                      case 'instagram-media':
                        return null;
                      case 'twitter-tweet':
                        return buildForTwitter(e.outerHtml);
                    }
                  }

                  return null;
                },
              ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(15)),
            if (paragraphs.length > 1)
              Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(10)),
                  const ShowAdmobWidget(),
                  ...paragraphs.sublist(1).map((paragraph) {
                    return Column(
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(10)),
                        HtmlWidget(
                          paragraph,
                          textStyle: TextStyle(
                            color: Theme.of(context).splashColor,
                            fontSize: ScreenUtil().setSp(14),
                            height: 1.5,
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    );
                  }),
                ],
              ),
            if (post.data['galleryItems'] != null &&
                post.data['galleryItems'].length > 1)
              SizedBox(
                height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(200),
                child: CarouselSlider(
                  options: CarouselOptions(
                    aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                    enlargeCenterPage: true,
                  ),
                  items: List<Widget>.from(
                    post.data['galleryItems'].map((item) {
                      return GestureDetector(
                        onTap: () {
                          Navigator.push(
                            context,
                            MaterialPageRoute(
                              builder: (_) => FullscreenImageScreen(
                                imageUrl: item,
                              ),
                            ),
                          );
                        },
                        child: ClipRRect(
                          borderRadius:
                              BorderRadius.circular(ScreenUtil().setWidth(10)),
                          child: CachedNetworkImage(
                            imageUrl: item,
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          ),
                        ),
                      );
                    }),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            SizedBox(height: ScreenUtil().setHeight(10)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  List<String> extractParagraphs(String htmlContent) {
    final galleryPattern = RegExp(r'\[gallery[^\]]*]');
    final captionPattern = RegExp(r'\[caption[^\]]*](.*?)\[\/caption]');

    // Remove gallery tags
    final filteredContent = htmlContent.replaceAll(galleryPattern, '');

    // Remove caption tags and keep the caption text
    final processedContent =
        filteredContent.replaceAllMapped(captionPattern, (match) {
      final captionText = match.group(1)!;
      return captionText;
    });

    final parsedHtml = parser.parse(processedContent);
    final elements = parsedHtml.getElementsByTagName('p');

    if (elements.isNotEmpty) {
      final paragraphs = elements.map((element) => element.outerHtml).toList();

      // Filter de gewenste paragrafen op basis van de klasse "p1"
      final filteredParagraphs = paragraphs.where((paragraph) {
        final paragraphElement = parser.parse(paragraph);
        final classes = paragraphElement.getElementsByTagName('p')[0].classes;
        return !classes.contains('p1');
      }).toList();

      return filteredParagraphs;
    }

    final lineBreakPattern = RegExp(r'<br[^>]*\/?>');
    final filteredLineBreaks = processedContent.split(lineBreakPattern);

    // Replace Instagram links with clickable text
    final instagramPattern = RegExp(
        r'https:\/\/www\.instagram\.com\/p\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\/\?[\w=&;%#]+');
    final updatedContent = filteredLineBreaks.map((line) {
      if (instagramPattern.hasMatch(line)) {
        final instagramLink = instagramPattern.firstMatch(line)!.group(0)!;
        return '<a href="$instagramLink">$instagramLink</a>';
      } else {
        return line;
      }
    }).toList();

    return updatedContent;
  }

  Widget buildForTwitter(String blockquoteOuterHtml) {
    return Html(
      data: blockquoteOuterHtml,
      customRender: {
        'iframe': (RenderContext context, Widget child, attributes, _) {
          return buildTwitterWidget(attributes);
        },
      },
      customEdgeInsets: (node) {
        if (node.localName == 'blockquote') {
          return EdgeInsets.all(10.0);
        }
        return null;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget buildTwitterWidget(Map<String, String> attributes) {
    final src = attributes['src'];
    if (src != null && src.contains('platform.twitter.com')) {
      final queryParamIndex = src.indexOf('?');
      final tweetId =
          queryParamIndex != -1 ? src.substring(queryParamIndex + 1) : '';
      return Container(
        width: double.infinity,
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
          child: WebView(
            initialUrl:
                'https://platform.twitter.com/embed/index.html?$tweetId',
            javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
          ),
        ),
      );
    }
    return SizedBox.shrink();
  }

  String formatDate(String date) {
    final dateFormat = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy');
    return dateFormat.format(DateTime.parse(date));
  }
}
```

I'm having trouble rendering the Twitter block properly in the app.  Because it works now with controllers. The current implementation uses an older version of flutter_html, but I would like to switch to flutter_html version 4.2.2 for better rendering and performance. How can I modify the buildForTwitter method to achieve the desired rendering using flutter_html?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Import the necessary packages:

```
import 'package:flutter_html/flutter_html.dart';
import 'package:flutter_html/html_parser.dart';
```

Modify the buildForTwitter method:

```
Widget buildForTwitter(String blockquoteOuterHtml) {
  return Html(
    data: blockquoteOuterHtml,
    customRender: {
      'iframe': (RenderContext context, Widget child, attributes, _) {
        return buildTwitterWidget(attributes);
      },
    },
    customEdgeInsets: (node) {
      if (node.localName == 'blockquote') {
        return EdgeInsets.all(10.0);
      }
      return null;
    },
  );
}

Widget buildTwitterWidget(Map<String, String> attributes) {
  final src = attributes['src'];
  if (src != null && src.contains('platform.twitter.com')) {
    final queryParamIndex = src.indexOf('?');
    final tweetId = queryParamIndex != -1 ? src.substring(queryParamIndex + 1) : '';
    return Container(
      width: double.infinity,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: AspectRatio(
        aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
        child: WebView(
          initialUrl: 'https://platform.twitter.com/embed/index.html?$tweetId',
          javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
  return SizedBox.shrink();
}
```

Comment: Thanks but i keep getting some packages, for example webview, is not found. This is now WebViewWidget i believe. Also the customrender is not defined, I shared a more extensive code for what i use it in

Als html_parser is not null safety so i cannot use it in my flutter version. Tried html_parser_plus but no luck also